# Form <td> get data for post method

Tags: html, node.js, html-table

Is it possible to get data from td in a html table like you would with a input?

```
<form action="/user/editUser" method="post">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
        </td>
        <td name="firstName"><%= user.firstName %></td>
        <td name="lastName"><%= user.lastName %></td>

    </tr>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tables are not form elements, so they are ignored when a form is submitted. One thing you could do is with Javascript is to override the submit event for the form and perform an Ajax post to your action. First add an id to your form. (<form id="myForm" ...>). I would also add error handling to this.

#### Sample

```
<script>
    $('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var firstName = $('td[name="firstName"]').html();
        var lastName = $('td[name="lastName"]').html();

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/user/editUser',
            data: {
                firstName,
                lastName,
            },
            success: (res) => {
                // do something
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume by "like you would with a input" you're referring to an input's `.value` property, and the data you're interested in is the `user.firstName` and `user.lastName` after your HTML has been templated? If so, then `<td>` doesn't have a `.value` property.

Instead, you access the inner HTML or the inner text of a `td` (or any tag) by using `.innerHTML` and `.innerText` properties, respectively.